# I'm getting 0 when I evalute an integral I know is non-zero

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Here is my code:

```
ClearAll[n, y];
Integrate[(1 - y^n)/(1 - y^2), {y, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> Re[n] > -1]
```

When I evaluate it, Mathematica 12.0 is giving me $0$, but I believe the correct answer is

$\qquad 
{1 \over2}\left[\Psi\left(n + 1 \over 2\right) - \Psi\left(1 \over 2\right)\right]$

where $\Psi$ is the `Digamma` function.

Comment: In 12.2.0.0 I get `(1/2)*(HarmonicNumber[(1/2)*(-1 + n)] + Log[4])`

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful.  (There's also the triple back-tick, which maybe you meant to do.)

Comment: I get the same as @Andreas in V12.0.0.

Comment: Same result as @Andreas with 12.0.0.0 (and 10.4.1.0 and 12.1.1.0) on Windows 10.

Comment: Retry with a fresh kernel?

Comment: There were not mispelling. It happens because the software has bad behaviors. Or stackexchange has interests in Wolfram...

Answer (score 2):

Try restarting Mathematica

```
$Version

(* "12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

expr = Integrate[(1 - y^n)/(1 - y^2), {y, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> Re[n] > -1]

(* 1/2 (HarmonicNumber[1/2 (-1 + n)] + Log[4]) *)
```

Verifying that this is equivalent to your expected result

```
expr == 1/2 (PolyGamma[(n + 1)/2] - PolyGamma[1/2]) // FullSimplify

(* True *)
```

Comment: Thanks. I Quit and Start the Kernel. It's working fine right now.